# sparse-dense multiplication in matlab

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix, blas

Consider A*B in Matlab. A and B are matrices.

IF A and B are both dense it will call regular BLAS i.e. dGEMM.

What happens under the hood (which sparse library functions does Matlab call) if A and B are

1. both in sparse format.
2. A is in sparse format and B is dense format or A is in dense format and B is in sparse format.

Comment: I believe that Matlab leverages [SuiteSparse](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html) for these operations, but I'm not certain if this is still true.

Comment: thanks this is useful